# VS ServiceStack Template - Requires Git to be installed

Tags: visual-studio, servicestack

I am trying to use ServiceStack templates to create a new project on Visual Studio 2015 Professional.

Some of the templates seem to require an installation of Git. I faithfully download & install Git on my Windows PC. Additionally I have restarted PC & VS multiple times.

However, the below popup keeps on coming when I look to create a new project from a VS Servicestack template.

[image]

Comment: Could you check to make sure `git` is available on your PATH? Eg, you are able to run `git --version` from any command line and get it to show which version of git is installed? The extension tries to find git on your PATH before showing that dialog.

Comment: Thanks @Layoric, I have added that as a formal answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add into PATH:

1. Right-Click on My Computer.
2. Click on Advanced System Settings.
3. Click on Environment Variables.
4. Then, under System Variables, look for the path variable and click edit.
5. Add the path to git's bin and cmd at the end of the string like this: C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin